# Cannot use PhotoCapture by importing 'UnityEngine.Windows.WebCam' by can access UnityEngine.Windows.WebCam.PhotoCapture in Unity

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, hololens

I'm using Unity 2019.4.26f1 (I'm working on a legacy project for my company) and I'm trying to capture images from a Hololens 2 using this [official Unity tutorial](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.4/Documentation/ScriptReference/Windows.WebCam.PhotoCapture.html).

While I've managed to make it work I'd like to understand this behaviour. When I use the classes inside the Webcam namespace, like PhotoCapture, sometimes I get a weird behaviour.

For instance, I can use classes like `PhotoCaptureFrame`, `CapturePixelFormat`, among others, but when it comes to PhotoCaptureResult, inside of PhotoCapture, doing  `PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult` doesn't work. The only solution appears to be to use the whole path (`UnityEngine.Windows.WebCam.PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult`) to access this class. I don't mind doing it but I want to know WHY this happens.

I've checked that I'm using the docs from the right version, and that I've enabled .NET 4.X in my settings, but the issue is still there.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Could you provide a [MCVE]? And have you tried to regenerate the vs project?

Comment: My code is the one in the Unity link. In a 3D Unity project, create a scene and attach that code to a GameObject. You should see the behaviour I describe. I cannot regenerate the vs project because I cannot reach the point of being able to generate it because of this exception in Unity

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue in `2019.4.26f1`.  Please update your [Unity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/choosing-unity-version) and [Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/install-the-tools) to our recommended version

Answer (score 2):

Hi I’m Wayne Wang from the Microsoft for Founders Hub team!

In my experience, "UnityEngine.Windows.WebCam.PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult" works but a class with a default namespace does not, must be some IL2CPP generation issue: it got confused on namespace.

Please ensure that your projects, your local namespaces, your own classes were not naming as "UnityEngine" "Windows" "WebCam" "PhotoCapture". If it is, please change them.

If it not the case, I would second @billy's advice: Please try update unity, visual studio, and related compiling tools you installed if possible.